# How to evaluate the current field value using a FieldArray?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Is it possible to get the current value of a field while using a `FieldArray`? For example, I have the following code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Form, ArrayField, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  initialValues: {
    customers: state.currentOffice.customers
  }
});

const renderCustomers = (fields, meta) => (
  <Container>
  {
    fields.map((customer, index) => (
      <Row>
        <Col lg='6'>
          <span>{ /* I need the current customer name be shown here */ }</span>

          <Field
            name={`${customer}.name`}
            component='input'
            className='form-control'
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    ))
  }
  </Container>
);

const MyForm = reduxForm({ form: 'customersForm' })((props) => (
  <Form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
    <FieldArray name='customers' component={renderCustomers} />
  </Form>
));

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyForm);
```

I need the customer name be shown in line 18, but when I try to evaluate the customer name between the JSX curly braces, I receive literally `customers[0].name`.

Is it possible to achieve that using redux-form?

Comment: maybe you have a typo because the argument is `customer` and you are using `customers[0].name` with an `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`fields.get(index)`](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/#-code-fields-get-index-function-code-) is the answer you seek.